# JQuery $.each() JSON array object iteration

Tags: jquery, json, each

I am having some real difficulty attempting to solve a JQuery $.each() iteration

This is my array, limiting results for convenience

```
[{"GROUP_ID":"143",
  "GROUP_TYPE":"2011 Season",
  "EVENTS":[
    {"EVENT_ID":"374","SHORT_DESC":"Wake Forest"},
    {"EVENT_ID":"376","SHORT_DESC":"Yale"},
    {"EVENT_ID":"377","SHORT_DESC":"Michigan State"}]
 },
 {"GROUP_ID":"142",
  "GROUP_TYPE":"2010 Season",
  "EVENTS":[
    {"EVENT_ID":"370","SHORT_DESC":"Duke"},
    {"EVENT_ID":"371","SHORT_DESC":"Northwestern"},
    {"EVENT_ID":"372","SHORT_DESC":"Brown"}]
}]
```

My first $.each iteration works very well, but the sub iteration for "EVENTS" is where I am having issues

My first $.each() function

```
     $.each(json, function(key) {

            html = '<a href="'+json[key].GROUP_ID+'">';

     ....
```

My non-working second $.each() function

```
     $.each(json.EVENTS, function(key) {
    newHTML += '<p>'+json.EVENTS[key].SHORT_DESC+'</p>';


     ...
```

I am understanding (loosely) that this is not a singular JSON object, but a JSON array of objects, but not understanding if the first version works why the second does not

the end result I want to achieve once I understand this is an $.each() within an $.each(), I know the code below does not work, and more than likely idiotic, but gives an idea of what im trying to achieve : iterate through parent then child by parent

```
$.each(json, function(key) {

            html = '<a href="'+json[key].GROUP_ID+'">';

     $.each(json[key].EVENTS, function(subkey) {

            html = '<a href="'+json[key]EVENTS[subkey].SHORT_DESC+'">';
 ...
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Assign the second variable for the `$.each function()` as well, makes it lot easier as it'll provide you the data (so you won't have to work with the indicies).

```
$.each(json, function(arrayID,group) {
            console.log('<a href="'+group.GROUP_ID+'">');
    $.each(group.EVENTS, function(eventID,eventData) {
            console.log('<p>'+eventData.SHORT_DESC+'</p>');
     });
});
```

Should print out everything you were trying in your question.

http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/hZsQS/

**edit** renamed the variables to make it bit easier to understand what is what.

Comment: That's a beautiful thing, works like a charm. I really appreciate your response, accurate and easy to implement, thanks again