# Returning JSON data with ajax in wordpress

Tags: ajax, json, wordpress

Ok so a fairly long question here. I'm fairly new to AJAX and especially using it in the context of WordPress, but I've been following along some tutorials online and I think I'm almost there.

I'll paste what I have so far and explain my thinking.

Ok so to start, the JS.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
     jQuery('.gadgets-menu').mouseenter(function(){

          doAjaxRequest();
     });
});
```

Mouse enters .gadgets-menu and the request triggers, using mouseenter so it fires once.

The request itself.

```
function doAjaxRequest(){
     // here is where the request will happen
     jQuery.ajax({
          url: 'http://www.mysite.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
          data:{
               'action':'do_ajax',
               'fn':'get_latest_posts',
               'count':5
               },
          dataType: 'JSON',
          success:function(data){
                //Here is what I don't know what to do.                 

                             },
          error: function(errorThrown){
               alert('error');
               console.log(errorThrown);
          }


     });

}
```

Now the php function.

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_do_ajax', 'our_ajax_function');
add_action('wp_ajax_do_ajax', 'our_ajax_function');
function our_ajax_function(){


     switch($_REQUEST['fn']){
          case 'get_latest_posts':
               $output = ajax_get_latest_posts($_REQUEST['count']);
          break;
          default:
              $output = 'No function specified, check your jQuery.ajax() call';
          break;

     }


         $output=json_encode($output);
         if(is_array($output)){
        print_r($output);   
         }
         else{
        echo $output;
         }
         die;
}
```

And the ajax_get_latest_posts function

```
function ajax_get_latest_posts($count){
     $posts = get_posts('numberposts='.'&category=20'.$count);

     return $posts;
}
```

So, if I've done this right the output should be `$posts = get_posts('numberposts='.'&category=20'.$count);` ie. the number of posts (5), from category 20.
I don't know what to do with that now, how do I get the title and the thumbnail?

I'm sorry if this is silly, I'm just fumbling around here.

Amended php

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_do_ajax', 'our_ajax_function');
add_action('wp_ajax_do_ajax', 'our_ajax_function');
function our_ajax_function(){


      $output = ajax_get_latest_posts($_REQUEST['count']); // or $_GET['count']
    if($output) {
        echo json_encode(array('success' => true, 'result' => $output));
    }
    else {
        wp_send_json_error(); // {"success":false}
        // Similar to, echo json_encode(array("success" => false));
        // or you can use, something like -
        // echo json_encode(array('success' => false, 'message' => 'Not found!'));
    } 

         $output=json_encode($output);
         if(is_array($output)){
        print_r($output);   
         }
         else{
        echo $output;
         }
         die;
}


function ajax_get_latest_posts($count)
{
    $args = array( 'numberposts' => $count, 'order' => 'DESC','category' => 20 );
    $post = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
    if( count($post) ) {
        return $post;
    }
    return false;
}
```

This does not work.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
     jQuery('.gadgets-menu').mouseenter(function(){

          doAjaxRequest();
     });
});
function doAjaxRequest(){
     // here is where the request will happen
     jQuery.ajax({
          url: 'http://localhost:8888/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
          data:{
               'action':'do_ajax',
               'fn':'get_latest_posts',
               'count':5
               },
          dataType: 'JSON',
          success:function(data){
            if(data.success) {
               alert("It works");


                        }
            else {
                // alert(data.message); // or whatever...
            }
        }


     });

}
```

No alert is shown.

Comment: have you checked the network tab on Chrome Dev Tools to check the response status and text? also are you sure the url for the ajax call is correct? aren't you missing the name of your folder/site or are you working on the root of htdocs on your localhost?

Answer (score 9):

In your code `get_posts('numberposts='.'&category=20'.$count);` is wrong, but you can use [wp_get_recent_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_recent_posts) function instead (though it uses `get_posts` anyway), for example

```
function ajax_get_latest_posts($count)
{
    $args = array( 'numberposts' => $count, 'order' => 'DESC','category' => 20 );
    $post = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
    if( count($post) ) {
        return $post;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then in your `our_ajax-function` you can use

```
    $output = ajax_get_latest_posts($_REQUEST['count']); // or $_GET['count']
    if($output) {
        echo json_encode(array('success' => true, 'result' => $output));
    }
    else {
        wp_send_json_error(); // {"success":false}
        // Similar to, echo json_encode(array("success" => false));
        // or you can use, something like -
        // echo json_encode(array('success' => false, 'message' => 'Not found!'));
    }
```

In you `success` callback function, you can then check

```
success:function(data){
    if(data.success) {
        // loop the array, and do whatever you want to do
        $.each(data.result, function(key, value){
            // you can use $(this) too
            // console.log($(this)); // check this for debug and get an idea
        });
    }
    else {
        // alert(data.message); // or whatever...
    }
}
```

You can read [here](http://heera.it/ajax-functions-wordpress-3-5) about `wp_send_json_error` helper function to learn more about helper functions.

### Update :

Also remember that, after `$output=json_encode($output);` the `$output` is not an array anymore, instead, it's a `json` string, so `is_array($output)` will return false but if you use `is_array()` just before you encode it using `$output=json_encode($output);` like

```
if( is_array( $output ) ) {
    $output = json_encode( $output );
}
```

In this case, `is_array( $output )` will return `true`.

[**An example/simulation**.](http://jsfiddle.net/hZsQS/343/)

Comment: And how to actually output that on the page with JS?

Comment: You have to `loop` the `result` and `append` each row/some fields in the page.

Comment: Forgive me, Sheikh, but I don't know how to do that with JS! That was actually my question.

Comment: If you get `posts` then `data.results` (according to my answer) will contain all the post as an array of `Javascript` objects and you can loop using [$.each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) ([check this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6298599/jquery-each-json-array-object-iteration)) or [for()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for).

Comment: I'm checking the console and I'm not getting anything whatsoever when the mouseenter happens, though I can see in the network log that it is requesting data @wp-admin. I'll amend my question with your code.

Comment: Yes, in my answer but you have made mistakes in your question's code (i mentioned in my answer).

Comment: Well I'm doing testing and it won't display an alert for data.success, edited my question.

Comment: Try `console.log(data)` in your `success` callback, before `if(data.success)` and see what you get in the console.

Comment: Console log in firebug shows `GET http://localhost:8888/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=do_ajax&fn=get_latest_posts&count=5`, console log in chrome shows nothing. Even without console.log(data) firebug shows the same thing.

Comment: Do you have a category with id `20`, change the category in the example i've used and see what you get.

Comment: Yeah I definitely have a category ID 20, I changed it to 12 and some others and it gives the same message in firebug.

Comment: Instead of `echo json_encode(array('success' => true, 'result' => $output));` try `print_r($output);exit;` and se what you get in the console, don't forget `console.log(data)`.

Comment: Same console message with `print_r($output);exit;` `GET http://localhost:8888/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=do_ajax&fn=get_latest_posts‌​&count=5`

Comment: Check `function our_ajax_function(){ exit('function called'); }` and see if it works and check this thing step by step.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. If I replace `function our_admin_ajax` with that, the page just doesn't load at all.

Comment: This is to make sure that your function is working, just put `exit('function is working')` in side you function, at first line and see if you get `function is working` in the console.

Comment: Nope, I get the same message in the console, again. 
Perhaps you want to amend your answer with the full php code just to be extra sure I'm not doing something really stupid? I appreciate your help by the way, you're awesome.

Comment: Is this a live site, if it's then give me your link or I'm sorry because I don't know what's going on.

Comment: It's not a live site :/

Comment: How can I help you then ?

Comment: I don't know, I guess I'll just have to accept defeat on this one, thanks for trying though.

Comment: Maybe you can wait other answers or post the question on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Yeah I may well do that, Sheikh, I really appreciate you trying though, you're a champion.