# Wordpress AJAX: Get a function as Json response

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, wordpress

I'd like to get a function as Json response in my Ajax call, after the document is ready. I'm not sure if I'm on the right way but here is what I did so far:

My Html

```
<!--Where i want to load my function-->
<div id="applications"></div>
```

My Ajax/Jquery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    init_applications();
});
function init_applications(){
    var app_data = new FormData();
    app_data.append('action', 'applications');
    app_data.append('uid', uid);
    app_data.append('pid', pid);
    jQuery.ajax({
        method: 'post',
        url: ajaxurl,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: app_data,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        beforeSend:function(data){
            //something
        },
        success:function(data) {
            $('#applications').html(data.htmlapp);
            //console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(data){
            //console.log(data);
        }
    });
    //alert("a");
}
```

Of course in my **functions.php**

```
add_action('wp_ajax_applications', 'applications');
function applications(){
    $uid = $_POST['uid'];
    $pid = $_POST['pid'];
    $applications = inside_applications();
    $response = array('htmlapp'=>$applications);
    wp_send_json( $response );
}
```

and Finally I've created my separate function always in **functions.php**

```
function inside_applications(){
   //Some html code and instructions
}
```

Is this possible or I'm totally out of the way? Can you please give me some directions eventually? Many thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Returning JSON data with ajax in wordpress](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17982078/returning-json-data-with-ajax-in-wordpress)

Comment: @Dez Uh sorry. I've searched a lot but I didn't check that solution. Thanks.

Comment: With a fast read, the only thing i see, is in your function applications : you need to exit() or wp_die() at the end.

Comment: @Benoti thanks for your answer but I think that `wp_send_json()` hook print and die() already, according to the WP Codex.

Comment: You're right,! Sorry

Comment: @Benoti very welcome actually. If you have any other suggestion please share! thanks.

Comment: But you can not invoke your js function in your php function. For me $applications and $response are not good. The datas from the js arrive with $_POST, $résponse must be compose from data or another function(php).

Comment: @Benoti Yes It's possible I did it actually, but thanks for your comment, I will give my answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the previous reasoning was fine, it's just matter to return values or html in the function you want include. In my case was.

```
function inside_applications(){
   //Some html code and instructions
   $html = '<div class="something>everything</div>';
   $html .= '<div class="solved">solved</div>';
   //Insert some if or instructions
   return $html;
}
```

As discussed in comments `wp_send_json()` hook already `print()` and `die()` so it's not necessary to do anything more. Maybe there are other better methods to accomplish that but my objective was to Ajaxify a Wordpress theme and to have separate multiple functions refreshable and ready for my jQuery calls and actions.